# How to configure Laravel 5.7 with Redis TLS (Using phpredis)

Tags: laravel, redis, phpredis

I'm using laravel 5.7 with phpredis (PHP 7.2), but I’m not able to get it to work with tls, I am trying to use it with digitalocean Redis managed database which only supports tls connection

Any idea if tls even supported with laravel/phpredis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this to work, basically the current phpredis version that is shipped with php 7.2 (Ubuntu 18) is old and does not support tls, to fix this I had to update phpredis from pecl (https://pecl.php.net/package/redis)